# assigning belongsTo values to and Ember model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Lets say a deposit belongs to a bankAccount: `DS.belongsTo('bank-account', { async: true})`

When retrieving a given `deposit` the `bankAccount` and all its data is in that deposit's JSON payload:

`deposit: {links: [{rel: "self", href: null}], id: "6c71da6c-c915-4361-97a5-…}
bank_account_id: "02b37863-f968-4455-9252-8bc1681ba4e7"
  bank_account: {account_type: ..., ..., ...}
    account_type: "checking"
    bank_name: "..."
    id: "02b37863-f968-4455-9252-8bc1681ba4e7"
    ...
    ...`

So for a given instance of `deposit` I expected  `deposit.get('bankAccount')` to return an instance of `bankAccount` with the data already embedded in the `deposit`'s json payload.  Instead it returns a promise, despite already having all the data for that deposit's `bankAccount`.  Why does it behave this way?  Am I doing something wrong and is there a way to implement the desired behavior?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

check the store using the ember inspector

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

check the bankAccount model type under the data tab and see if it is putting the record in it correctly when the payload comes down, it seems to prolly be throwing it away (not putting it in the store) so that when you do the get, it triggers a promise, which adapter are you using? also I see the links in the payload, it might be getting confused

Comment: flylib thanks for the tips.  I started doing that but threads like these wound up being helpful too.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1516 and https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `serializers/deposit.js` with the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and telling it to embed `bankAccount` worked.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
  attrs: {
    bankAccount: {embedded:'always'}
  }
});
```